# ng-repeat fails on a p>div structure, but works for a div>div structure?

Tags: angularjs

I'm maintaining a legacy product, and found a quirk that I haven't seen before in AngularJS.

As demonstrated in [this Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/DK2CWV791XbgrGnE?open=index.html&preview), the following HTML fails to render:

```js
<p ng-repeat="item in items">
  <div>{{item.type}}</div>
</p>
```

while this renders just fine:

```js
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <div>{{item.type}}</div>
</div>
```

Is there any explanation as to why this might be the case?

I was rather caught off-guard with this, as I don't recall seeing anything about this in the development resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It most likely is due to the fact that [the HTML spec specifies](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-p-element) that for a `<p>` immediately followed by a `<div>`, the close tag is optional.

I would assume this means that somehow the browser silently ignores the presence of any explicit source-specified `</p>` tag. I'd guess that when `ng-repeat` is parsing the source, it then cannot find the end of the repeated section, and therefore cannot render as expected.